# Boost Graph undirected traversal of directed graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am using Boost Graphs. The edges of my graph have a directed meaning. Thats why I chose a directed graph. However when I traverse the graph, I usually want to do this ignoring the direction. However I haven't found a solution to traverse my graphs for example using the built in depth first search.

Is there a solution for this that does not involve making a copy of the whole graph?

If there isn't: I am unsure whether my graph is actually directed by nature. Maybe I should use an undirected graph, and add some "direction" properties? I am not sure how to do that though (simply attaching the source/target vertex_descriptors to the edge would obviously break once the graph changes). Is there a possibility to do this? Does it make sense at all?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about the Boost Graphs implementation. Could you describe your original task a little bit?

Comment: Well basically I have nodes which represent positions in 3d space. Now the edge from node A to node B is attached a transformation matrix that transforms from coordinate system A to B. My algorithm performs some optimization on the node positions of this graph. As a preprocessing step, I need to traverse the graph using BFS/DFS/whatever and compute something - and I dont care about the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about Boost Graphs implementation but I can see two options in your case.

1. If your graphs are not big, than you could just create a non directed graph first, compute your "something" and then create a directed copy. This should take `O(n)` time and will not affect the overall performance.
2. Use not directed graph and add some information about the direction to the edge, like the pointer to the source vertex. This solution could make your algorithms a bit more complicated but you'll avoid any copying of data and gain some performance on big graphs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hm well as for 1) I essentially agree its a solution. However its kind of ugly because essentially all algorithms could be executed without this -- the information is there. But I guess I'll have to consider this solution if I can't find any other way to do it. As for 2) I have already suggested this in the original question... but here the question is how to do this in boost graph since you cannot use the source vertex_descriptor in the edge (I know you've written you are not familiar with BGL... maybe someone else has an idea here)